# Snap to midpoint of page edge does not work

Tags: inkscape

When activating `snap to and from bounding box edges` it does not snap to the pages borders. It looks like the page is not a bounding box.

However when activating `snap to page border`it does snap to the page borders, but to every single point of it.

Is there no way to accomplish this without creating a grid?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple object, e.g., a rectangle.
2. Go to the alignment tab and select *relative to: page.*
3. Use *centre on horizontal axis* and *align left edges of objects to the right edge of the anchor.*

You now have an object, the midpoint of whose bounding box edge is identical to the midpoint of the right page edge. To get similar objects for the other edges, change step 3 in the above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're close enough to the corner of the page, then Inkscape will snap to that corner. If you're further away from a page corner, but still close enough to the page's edge, then Inkscape will snap to the edge.

It is not clear to me though what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to fit the bounding box of an object to the paper?

You might want to try Inkscape 0.91, which was released recently. It has lots of improvements, including ones related to snapping.